# How can I change the some specific text on Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, settings

I looked up en_GB.po file but It seems the text that I want to change it's not in the en_GH.po file.
Screenshot for which I want to change.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, 90% of WordPress theme developers tend to use: `functions.php` for most of the theme structure. So I recommend to start looking up there.

If that image you embed is the home page of your theme, then look up into: `index.php / index-loop.php / loop.php / home.php`

If It is a category, then look up into: `category.php / archive.php / index.php`

If It is a page, then look up into: `page.php`

In case you theme has way too many pages, I recommend you to download the theme folder to your desktop and run notepad ++ . Now drag the entire folder into Notepad ++ and all the pages will be opened. When it's done click ctrl + F, type what you are looking for and then click find all in all opened documents.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply.
Yes it is homepage, but my question is where are the index.php that you mentioned  located at ftp ?

Comment: open up your website on a browser and check the code source for a path that says something like this: `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/themes/here-theme-name/`